# How to change row class based on the cells' values in griddle-react?

Tags: reactjs, griddle

I have a table in griddle (v 1.13.1) and I want to highlight some rows.

```
var data = [{highlight:true, name:"Abc"},
            {highlight:false, name:"Abc"},
            {highlight:true, name:"Abc"}]

<Griddle 
   data={data} />
```

I want to add class to all rows, which have highlight==true. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of how [`<Row>`](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/blob/master/src/components/Row.js) component is implemented, you can then define your own. The  component accepts a `components` props, and you can add there your own logic there as I did in the below demo.

```js
var data = [
  { highlight: true, name: "Abc" },
  { highlight: false, name: "Abc" },
  { highlight: true, name: "Abc" }
];

const TableRow = ({
  Cell,
  griddleKey,
  columnIds,
  onClick,
  onMouseEnter,
  onMouseLeave,
  style,
  className,
  rowData
}) => {
  const appliedClassName = rowData.highlight
    ? `${className} my-own-class`
    : className;
  return (
    <tr
      key={griddleKey}
      onClick={onClick}
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      style={style}
      className={appliedClassName}
    >
      {columnIds &&
        columnIds.map(c => (
          <Cell
            key={`${c}-${griddleKey}`}
            griddleKey={griddleKey}
            columnId={c}
            style={style}
            className={className}
          />
        ))}
    </tr>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Griddle
        components={{
          Row: props => <TableRow {...props} />
        }}
        data={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/griddle-react/0.8.2/Griddle.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Note: For some reason this code doesn't work in SO editor.

Comment: Working code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/p5pp7lwrm0 . Demo https://p5pp7lwrm0.codesandbox.io/.